# Retrieving specific information from API

Tags: python

I hope you are doing ok.

I'm making a Python script to retrieve specific data from an API

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

####Make the call request for the API
username = "******"
password = "******"

url = "https://api.test./v1/2" #fake url 

headers = {"accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))


###Create a function to run the code

def information_retrieve():

    data = response.text

    #The API contains these sections I want to retrieve.
    info_data = data["advanced_computer_search"]["computers"] 


    fields_to_check = {

            "Computer_Name": "",
            "FileVault_2_Status": "",
            "Building": "",
            "Serial_Number": "",
            "FileVault_2_Individual_Key_Validation": "",
            "Full_Name": "",
            "Username": "",
            "Managed": "",
            "Department": ""

        }

    for item in info_data:
            print("MAC INFO ")
            for keys, value in fields_to_check.items():
                if keys in item:
                    field_value = item[keys]
                    if field_value:
                        print(f"{keys}: {field_value}")
                    else:
                        print(f"{keys}: ")
                else:
                    print(f"{keys}: ")
            print()
information_retrieve()
```

However, when I run the code I get this error message:

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

I've tried different things with the code, like this one:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))


#Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.text

    # Access specific information from the API response
    specific_info = data["advanced_computer_search"]

    # Use the retrieved information as needed
    print(specific_info)

else:
    print("Error: Failed to retrieve data from the API.")
```

But the same thing happens, I get the same error:

I made another script but this one is connected to a JSON file, it's basically the same thing, the only thing that changes is that I have the JSON file and I open it using

`with open(filename) as f:` 
If I use it in this way, it works, but If I want to do it directly from the API it does not work.

So, I'm trying to understand why it works in that way but it doesn't when I try to do it from the API directly. Does anyone know why this is happening? or what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: Could you post the full error trace? It seems that you're using string values instead of integers for indices in order to access the list's elements.

Comment: It should read `for key, value in fields_to_check.items():`, and obviously `key` in that case is a string. So `field_value = item[keys]` is bound to fail, as `item` is also a string.

Comment: Sure thing, this is the error:

File "/Users/***-***-tig/Desktop/Script-test2/main_test.py", line 21, in information_retrieve
    info_data = data["advanced_computer_search"]
                ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code in your IDE and setting a breakpoint to inspect data.text? Have you looked at the documentation for requests to see what structure the return value of get has? If you have done all these things, are you seeing something unexpected, different from what the documentation and your own debugging would suggest? It’s important to do due diligence on your own issues before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're parsing the response as a text, but treating it as JSON. If you're expecting the request to return a JSON response, then change the following line

```
data = response.text
```

to

```
data = response.json()
```